# Getting key values from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with indices as keys and timestamps as values. I wanted to get the keys for whose values there is a overlap.

ex:

```
{1: 19-13-30
    19-13-32
    19-13-33
    .
    .
    19-13-55,
 2: 19-13-25
    19-13-26
    19-13-27
    .
    .
    19-13-35,
  3:19-13-10
    19-13-31
    .
    .
    19-13-18}
```

For the above dictionary values of 1 and 2 overlap(19-13-30 to 19-13-35). So, I want to return the keys whenever there is a overlap. In this case 1 & 2

For calculating the overlap I am iterating over the values and storing the start time and end time in a list like [starttime,endtime]. Then I am checking for overlap by

```
   overlapping = [ [x,y] for x in intervals for y in intervals if x is not y and x[1]>y[0] and x[0]<y[0] ]
for x in overlapping:
    print '{0} overlaps with {1}'.format(x[0],x[1])
```

This prints the values which overlap.But instead I want the keys whose values overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In keeping with your code, this should be a minimal modification:

```
intervals= {1:[1,2], 2:[2,3], 3:[4,5], 4:[6,8], 5:[6.5,7]}
overlapping = [ [i,j,x,y] for i,x in intervals.iteritems() for j,y in intervals.iteritems() if x is not y and x[1]>y[0] and x[0]<y[0] ]
for x in overlapping:
    print '{0} overlaps with {1} at {2} and {3}'.format(x[2],x[3],x[0],x[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating over the intervals, you can iterate over the values (i.e. the positions in your interval list). Something like

```
keys = range(len(intervals))
overlapping = [ [x,y] for x in keys for y in keys if x is not y and intervals[x][1]>intervals[y][0] and intervals[x][0]<intervals[y][0] ]
```